# If this element is unidirectional or bidirectional ? (see the image)

Tags: circuit-analysis, basic, network

Below the I-V characteristics of two elements .Is these elements are  unidirectional or bidirectional ? 
[image]

Comment: It cannot be a single element in either example - it could be a bridge rectifier but that is four elements. This kind of invalidates your question so maybe some more context is needed. Basically you cannot get positive current flowing into "an element" when the voltage reverses. You can get positive current flowing into the load of a bridge rectifier with the input voltage reversed of course but, a bridge aint a simple element.

Comment: i understand what you are saying @andy. But if we consider bridge rectifier as single block with two terminal for input and another two terminal for output.Then this system will be a unidirectional or bidirectional system?

Comment: @Saurabh In that case, it would be unidirectional - but now you are looking at a black box (not a single element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that current flows in only one direction through the device, so I guess that means that it's "unidirectional" in that sense.

But the odd thing is that in one half of the diagram, the device is absorbing power, while in the other half, it is *generating* power. There's no real device that has a characteristic curve like the ones shown.

Devices like electrochemical cells, photovoltaic cells, capacitors, inductors, etc. have the ability to both absorb and provide power, but their V-I curves are very different from this.